# Using Streams with TestFactory

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java-8

I'm having this method

```
@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicTest> dynamicTestsFromStream() throws IOException {
    initialize();

    return Stream.of(core).map(
        str -> DynamicTest.dynamicTest("test" + str.toString(), () -> { Just for Testing > Assert.assertTrue(false); }));
}
```

My `core` Array contains Elements of Type `Tuple4`. `Tuple4(String a, String b, String c, String d)`.

When I'm trying to adress the name (i want `String c`) I get an error, and in the current example my
result for `str` is:`Tuple4@4d50efb8, Tuple4@7e2d773b, Tuple4@2173f6d9`

Can someone tell me how I can adress the right index for str? since `get(int)` won't work, because I can't get the current position?

**EDIT**

When I put `Stream.of("A","B","C").map(...);`
The test is given the right names "test A" ...

So how can I give `stream.of()` an Array(Object) to name the tests?

Comment: From which library you get class `Tuple4`?

Comment: I've implemented it myself. `Class Tuple4(String a, String b, ...)`
So normally I'd adress `String a` with `Tuple4.a`

Comment: In this case you can access like this:
`return Stream.of(core).map(
                str -> DynamicTest.dynamicTest("test" + str.a, () -> { Just for Testing > Assert.assertTrue(false); })
        );`

Comment: Tried that...
`[ERROR] symbol:   variable a
[ERROR] location: variable str of type java.util.List<Tuple4>`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with _junit_ or _junit5_ but rather with how to use streams, so I edited the tags.

Comment: Hm, thanks. Probably, yes. In addition I edited the title.

Comment: The error message saying `variable str of type java.util.List<Tuple4>` is a little weird if `core` is an array - are you sure it is not a `List`?

Comment: I've tried it in the end with a List. 
It's working with an array now.

But can you tell me why it won't work with a List<>?

Comment: You are having trouble starting the stream. If you have a collection, like a `List` simply call `.stream()` on it. This is not possible for arrays, so in that case use `Arrays.stream(...)`. The methods `Stream.of(...)` are meant for creating ad hoc streams for a few hard-coded elements like you did with `Stream.of("A","B","C")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Stream.of(SomeType[])` you run the risk of getting a stream containing just a single element, namely the array. Use [`Arrays::stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) instead.

Assuming `core` is of type `Tuple4[]` (if it is not, please include the actual type in the question), you can do as follows:

```
@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicTest> dynamicTestsFromStream() throws IOException {
    initialize();

    return Arrays.stream(core) // Stream<Tuple4>
            .map(tuple -> DynamicTest.dynamicTest(
                    "test " + tuple.c,
                    () -> { Assert.assertTrue(false); }
    ));
}
```